Is there a connection between Selberg's conjecture and the Burgess Bound / The Weyl Bound?
Lots of techniques for subconvexity estimates have barriers at the Burgess bound $\frac{3}{16}$ or the Weyl bound $\frac{1}{6}$. I've been curious to know if these bounds are somehow "natural" in a loose sense. That is, is there some heuristical way to expect it to be more difficult to surpass either bound apart from just experience.
This question was motivated by the following thought I had recently: the convexity bound is $\frac{1}{4}$ which is also (conveniently?) the lower bound we expect fo eigenvalues of Maass forms coming from Selberg's conjecture. Selberg was able to prove the bound $\frac{3}{16}$ which is the Burgess bound. Between subconvexity and lower bounds for eigenvalues, it seems like the same bounds are popping up but in the reverse order: $\frac{1}{4}$ is the trivial bound for subconvexity while its the conjectured lower bound for eigenvalues. Are these connected in some way that might help explain why the Burgess and Weyl bounds are "natural" barriers?
